# restarting a while loop in python for a new level

Tags: python

New to python (1st semester), I have a game that I am working on for my final project. I have written the code to do all I want for a "level" but I need to know how to make it start a new level if a condition is met. If I have a while loop already, should I create another loop outside for the level? (first post, so i'm not certain if this is enough info.) Thank you for anything you can provide.

```
while True:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    if (pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_RIGHT] != 0 ):
        newbasketx = basketx + 15
        if newbasketx <= 600:
            basketx = newbasketx
    if (pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_LEFT] != 0 ):
        newbasketx = basketx - 15
        if newbasketx >= 0:
            basketx = newbasketx

basket_rect = pygame.Rect(basketx, baskety, 200, 70)

for index in range (0,nFruits):

    fruity[index] = fruity[index] + fruitSpeed[index]
    thisFruit_rect = pygame.Rect (fruitx[index], fruity[index],150,75)

    if thisFruit_rect.colliderect (basket_rect):

        fruity[index] = random.randrange (-1000, -10)
        fruitx[index] = random.randrange (0,600)
        thisFruit = fruitList[index]
        if thisFruit == badpear:
            life = life -1
        if thisFruit == banana:
            score = score + 5
            totalScore = totalScore + 5
        if thisFruit == apple:
            score = score + 10
            totalScore = totalScore + 10
        if thisFruit == cherry:
            score = score + 15
            totalScore = totalScore + 15 
        if thisFruit == grapes:
            score = score + 1
            totalScore = totalScore + 1




    elif fruity[index] > height:
        fruity[index] = random.randrange (-1000, -10)
        fruitx[index] = random.randrange (0,600)
        fruitMiss = fruitMiss + 1
        if fruitMiss == 10:
            life = life - 1
            fruitMiss = 0



if life == 0:
    print 'game over'
    break




screen.fill(LIME)
for index in range (0,nFruits):

    screen.blit(fruitList[index],(fruitx[index],fruity[index]))
screen.blit(basket, (basketx, baskety))

pygame.display.update()
if score >= 100:
    life = life + 1
    score = 0
pygame.time.delay(15)
print 'total', totalScore, 'Score', score, 'Life', life, 'miss',fruitMiss
```

Comment: I don't want someone to do the work for me, I have looked up the question on this site and didn't find an explanation that would work for me. Should I create a def for level and then make a list that contains all the levels and it just iterates through until the end?

Comment: any suggestion will be vague at best since we don't know how you structured your code. You could provide a minimal example of what you have, but SO users don't know where your loops are and so we can't tell you where to put new logic

Comment: I understand that, guess I hoped there would be a simple "just do this" kinda answer.

Answer (score 2):

without knowing your specific structure this is very hard to answer. however, you could do something like this:

```
while level == 1:
    [do level 1 stuff]
while level == 2: 
    [do level 2 stuff]
```

etc.

you can use `break` to exit a while loop if the level is no longer the same.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) for more information about control structures in python!

Comment: Thank you, I prefer to learn trial by fire so I didn't post my code as I don't want someone to write it for me. I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `break` or `continue` statements to go out of your loop or in the next loop, see [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm) for a short introduction.

Comment: I have a break statement to end the program if life == 0, it seems with the continue statement will pass through or bypass the next letter in the string.  Would it be better to use the break statement at the end of a list? Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: You somehow have to nest your individual levels in a surrounding structure which goes through all levels (as long as `live > 0`). There are many different approaches for this.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into that.